# Get total number of lines of code for a user's PRs to a github repo

Tags: github, open-source, pull-request

How to get total number of lines of code (added and deleted) of a github user's pull requests to a certain github repo (optionally within a period of time)? Is there an easy way without writing code (or a hard way anyway)?

https://ossinsight.io/ is cool but it does not seem to have a way to run custom SQL query on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach (to be refined) would be to use the GitHub CLI gh, from within a local clone:

```
C:\Users\vonc\git\git>gh pr diff --patch 1382 | grep -E "file.? changed, "
 2 files changed, 29 insertions(+), 13 deletions(-)
```

Which refers to [PR 1382](https://github.com/git/git/pull/1382/files) of the `git/git` repository.

The other approach would be to use a GraphQL query (similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72905133/6309)) and start querying remote pull request that way.

---

The [OP yijiem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3317232/yijiem) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74748671/get-total-number-of-lines-of-code-for-a-users-prs-to-a-github-repo/74749126#comment131926038_74749126) using the first approach with:

> ```
> $ gh pr list --search "is:merged author:<name>" --json number --jq '.[].number' | \
> awk '{ system("gh pr diff --patch " $0) }' | \
> grep -E "file.? changed" | \
> awk '{ i+=$4; d+=$6 } END { print i,d }'
> ```
>
> The `--json` output format and `--jq` query option of `gh` are really nice!
> 8 hours ago

Comment: Thanks! I went with the first approach with a quick and dirty script such as: `$ gh pr list --search "is:merged author:<name>" --json number --jq '.[].number' | awk '{ system("gh pr diff --patch " $0) }' | grep -E "file.? changed" | awk '{ i+=$4; d+=$6 } END { print i,d }'`. The `--json` output format and `--jq` query option of `gh` are really nice!

Comment: @yijiem Well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.